# Fitting LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to fit LSTM model, but it gave me an error with the shape.

my dataset has 218 rows and 16 features including the targeted one.
I split the data, %80 for training and %20 for testing, after compiling the model and run it, i got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:    Specified a list with shape [160,1] from a tensor with shape [14,1]
     [[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
     [[functional_7/lstm_6/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_21740]
Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

Variable definitions:
`batch_size = 160`
`epochs = 20`
`timesteps = 15`

Here are the training and testing sets after reshaping:
`y_train = (174, 15, 1)`
`y_train = (174, 1, 1)`
`x_test = (44, 15, 1)`
`y_test = (44, 1, 1)`

My model:

[image]

the problem happens in this code when I fit the model:

[image]

Comment: my model:
inputs_1_mae = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, 1))
lstm_1_mae = LSTM(100, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(inputs_1_mae)
lstm_2_mae = LSTM(100, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(lstm_1_mae)
output_1_mae = Dense(units = 1)(lstm_2_mae)
regressor_mae = Model(inputs= inputs_1_mae ,outputs = output_1_mae)
regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae")
regressor_mae.summary()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: You have to change the shape of `y_train` if the input and the output of your model should have the same shape (check your model summary). Secondly, the number of samples, in your case 174, should be evenly divisible by the `batch_size` without remainder. So you can only use 1, 2, 3, 6, 29, 58, 87, or 174 as your batch size. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 2 
epochs = 20 
timesteps = 15

inputs_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, 1)) 
lstm_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(inputs_1_mae) 
lstm_2_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(lstm_1_mae) 
output_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1)(lstm_2_mae) 
regressor_mae = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inputs_1_mae ,outputs = output_1_mae) 
regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae") 
regressor_mae.summary() 

x_train = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1)) 
y_train = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1))

regressor_mae.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=2)
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(2, 15, 1)]              0         
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (2, 15, 100)              40800     
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (2, 15, 100)              80400     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (2, 15, 1)                101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 121,301
Trainable params: 121,301
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
87/87 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8092
Epoch 2/2
87/87 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8089
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5820061250>
```

**Update 1**:
To plot the mean square error of your training and test data, try something like this:

```py
x_train = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1)) 
y_train = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1))

x_test = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1)) 
y_test = tf.random.normal((174, 15, 1))

history = regressor_mae.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=25, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

plt.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error']) 
plt.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_error']) 
plt.title('model mean absolute error') 
plt.ylabel('mean_absolute_error') 
plt.xlabel('epoch') 
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left') 
plt.savefig('accuracy.png') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, it works now.

Any idea how can I show the accuracy also beside the loss? 

because I need to plot them to check if there is any over or underfitting.

Comment: Regarding your question, you can add a metric to your model like this: `regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae", metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])`

Comment: Thank you again, your answer is really helped and I already upvote the answer because it really deserves. 

I would like to ask one more question if you do not mind, I am trying to plot the accuracy between training and testing but it does not show the test line. Any ides?


plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('accuracy.png')
plt.show()

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: thank you, it is clear now, from the graph, do you think that there is underfitting ?

Comment: Kindly ask a new question regarding underfitting here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ since it does not have anything to do with the programming itself.

Comment: Your dataset is, by the way, really tiny.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to predict x-test using this code:

***results = regressor_mae.predict(x_test)***

But it gave me an error says: 


InvalidArgumentError:    Specified a list with shape [2,1] from a tensor with shape [32,1]
  [[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
  [[functional_5/lstm_4/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_15181]

Function call stack:
predict_function -> predict_function -> predict_function

any help for this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: Kindly ask a new question with these details please. It’s hard to answer / understand anything in the comments.